# Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.1' failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-07yg4mvk/psycopg2/

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, heroku

I want to push my Django app to heroku and I installed my requirements.txt file which is given below:

```
asgiref==1.1.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
attrs==17.4.0
autobahn==17.10.1
Automat==0.6.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
braintree==3.19.0
certifi==2017.11.5
cffi==1.11.2
chardet==3.0.4
chromedriver-installer==0.0.6
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.1.4
defusedxml==0.5.0
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==1.11
django-allauth==0.33.0
django-amp-tools==0.1.1
django-crispy-forms==1.5.0
django-filter==0.11.0
django-registration-redux==1.2
djangorestframework==3.7.1
gTTS==1.2.2
gTTS-token==1.1.1
gunicorn==19.7.1
hyperlink==17.3.1
idna==2.6
incremental==17.5.0
numpy==1.13.3
oauthlib==2.0.4
opencv-python==3.3.0.10
Pillow==5.0.0
psycopg2==2.7.4
PyAudio==0.2.11
pycparser==2.18
PyJWT==1.5.3
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
python-decouple==3.1
python-social-auth==0.3.6
python3-openid==3.1.0
pyttsx==1.1
pytz==2017.3
requests==2.7.0
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
selenium==3.7.0
six==1.11.0
social-auth-app-django==1.2.0
social-auth-core==1.4.0
SpeechRecognition==3.7.1
txaio==2.8.2
urllib3==1.22
virtualenv==15.1.0
whitenoise==3.3.1
zope.interface==4.4.3
```

After this I run this command `git-push heroku master` I am getting Error:

> could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.1' remote: remote: ---------------------------------------- remote: Command python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-07yg4mvk/psycopg2/ remote: ! Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

I have been unable to figure this out, please help.

Comment: Are you still able to reproduce this error? If so, do you have `runtime.txt` file? What does `heroku stack` show?

Comment: i got the solution thnks

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: i tried a lot but i was getting same error in last i uninstalled my PostgreSQL  10.1 after than i installed **PostgreSQL 10.2, 64-bit**  then it worked for me.

Comment: @davejagoda can you modify my all questions i am ban to ask question for that i have to correctly format all the question but i am new on stackoverflow  so please correct my questions

Comment: @davejagoda please this one also. thanks in advance
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966725/aws-credentials-setup-and-boto-exception