# aws/credentials setup and boto.exception

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

heroku does not serving the images from the **aws s3 bucket** i am using django as backend i already migrate my app. is heroku automatic serve all images from my pc(like in local development it serve's) or we have to again upload all the images ?

```html
 heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

and i am getting this error any idea

> boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request

**my setting.py file is:**

```html
"""
Django settings for ecommerce project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# from ecommerce.settings.aws.conf import *

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

# EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
# EMAIL_HOST_USER  = 'abc@gmail.com'
# EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'abc123'
# EMAIL_PORT = 587
# EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
# DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "rahul <abc@gmail.com>"
#
# ADMINS = [('rahul', EMAIL_HOST_USER)]
# MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '$$!#%(2lqx#ckmc9#j6lw5ts4_9n$qjy$@=zv09wxvo_=qa=po'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["shoppingwave.herokuapp.com"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products',
    'storages',
    'boto',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecommerce.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecommerce.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    # 'default': {
    #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    # }





    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'online_shopping',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'Rahul6612x',
            'HOST': '',
            'PORT': ''

        }
}

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'



DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME", "")
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = os.environ.get("AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN", "")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ.get("MEDIA_URL", "")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'























# MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
# STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#
#
#
# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static-storage'),
# )
#
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'live-static-files', "static-root")
# MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'live-static-files', "media-root")
#
#
#
# # STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static-serve', 'static_root')
# # MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static-serve', 'media_root')
#
# STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
#     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
#     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#
# )



# DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
# AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'darkmachine'
# AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'A55'
# AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '64E2hWFqCk'
# S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
# MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + '/media/'
#
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
# STATIC_URL = S3_URL + '/static/'
```

Comment: Don't post your Django SECRET_KEY publically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to [Heroku dashboard settings](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/kodefork/settings).

Then just enter all your environment variables like `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and etc....

Now, in **settings.py**

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "") 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME", "")
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False 
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = os.environ.get("AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN", "")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ.get("MEDIA_URL", "")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

This should work fine then.

You can follow [Amazon S3 bucket for storing media files of Django app on Heroku](http://www.kodefork.com/articles/amazon-s3-bucket-for-storing-media-files-of-django/) blog written by me for further understanding.

Comment: thnks the error gone away but when i am opening my app https://appname.herokuapp.com its working fine(still not serving images from s3 bucket)  but for this url 
https://appname.herokuapp.com/admin/  its showing  Server Error (500)

Comment: Try uploading new images, if still not serving then, check all the configurations you may have made some mistakes. Follow that blog link.

Comment: i tried lot but i am getting **Server Error (500)** on this url appname.herokuapp.com/admin  any idea.

Comment: Have you done `heroku run python manage.py migrate`, `heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser` and all that?

Comment: @RahulVerma, and this error is not because `s3 bucket`.

Comment: put your `settings.py` content here in question.

Comment: i added please check it

Comment: can you modify my all questions i am ban to ask question for that i have to correctly format all the question but i am new on stackoverflow so please correct my questions

Comment: bro i need your help take a look here https://github.com/jordn/heroku-django-s3/issues/1